# Can we change field type in patch org of manage package?

Tags: managed-package, custom-field

We have created a manage package which contains many custom fields. I know that we can not change the field type in manage package. My Question is can we change field type  in Patch org? or is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Patch orgs have the same restrictions as normal managed package development, except with even more of their own.

There's a good article on the salesforce docs about this that calls out the additional patch org restrictions:

1. New package components can’t be added.
2. Existing package components can’t be deleted.
3. API and dynamic Apex access controls can’t change for the package.
4. No deprecation of any Apex code.
5. No new Apex class relationships, such as extends, can be added.
6. No new Apex access modifiers, such as virtual or global, can be added.
7. No new Web services can be added.
8. No new feature dependencies can be added.

This is above and beyond the normal managed package development restrictions. They're usually used to backport bug fixes and conventionally not much more due to these restrictions, as well as the need to merge any changes back to your main packaging org.

Comment: Thank you @ca_pererson. Any workaround that you can recommend for this?

Comment: There's a pilot that lets you deprecate managed fields, but you'd have to help customers export and import data from the old to the new. Not easy, but possible

Comment: So can you, for example, make a text field longer in a patch org (which is allowed now in a normal package version)?

Comment: @keith no, you can't add any new components at all to a patch.

Comment: That would't be an addition, it would be a change in type to an existing field that is allowed in major revision changes. I'll expect the worst if the need ever comes up.

Comment: Ah, misread your comment. I don't know if that's possible but as it's changing existing metadata I'd *think* it's allowed.